# check is class has been added to <li> when radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for two radio buttons from the Give plugin:

```
<li class="give-gateway-option-selected">
  <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" 
     id="give-gateway-offline-987-1" value="offline">
  <label for="give-gateway-offline-987-1" 
    class="give-gateway-option" id="give-gateway-option-offline">
    Credit Card
  </label>
</li>
<li>
   <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" id="give- 
      gateway-paypal-987-1" value="paypal">
   <label for="give-gateway-paypal-987-1" class="give-gateway-option" 
      id="give-gateway-option-paypal"> PayPal
   </label>
</li>
```

If a radio button is checked then a class is added. 
Say I check the 'Credit Card' option. 
The following class is added:

```
<li class="give-gateway-option-selected">
<input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" 
id="give-gateway-offline-987-1" value="offline">
<label for="give-gateway-offline-987-1" 
class="give-gateway-option" id="give-gateway-option-offline"> Credit Card</label>
</li>
```

I need to write some javascript/jQuery to check if the radio box for 'credit card' is selected then redirect to a specific URL.
However I can't use

```
if ($('#give-gateway-offline-987-1').is(':checked'))) { //redirect code }
```

since no 'checked' value is added to the `<input>` rather a class is added to the `<li>` tag. 
How do I check if the class has been added and then run the redirect?

Comment: If the radio button is checked, it will indeed have the property of checked set to true.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3vuj0bhn/ verifies this behaviour

Comment: thank you I can see how it works now. How do I check if #give-gateway-offline-987-1 is selected and then add a href to redirect on form submit? please can you write a full answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

The :checked selector does work for radio buttons, see here: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

If you really need to use your class approach, check the parent jquery method if the structure remains as shown:

```
if($('#give-gateway-offline-987-1').parent().hasClass('give-gateway-option-selected')) {
    //redirect
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: Now the issue is that `closest()` will always return a jQuery object, which is truthy.  It may not have a result stack, but it will always not be null.  You need to check `.length`